# JS animation behind text

Tags: javascript, css, frontend

How can I mask web animation background with texts?
We have an animation [like this](https://bl58mf.csb.app). And it should fill the text layers.
Thanks for the help.
I have to make this in Webflow, but any idea could help!

Look&Feel design like this
[image: Look&Feel design like this]

Comment: Does [this article](https://css-tricks.com/how-to-do-knockout-text/) help you solve your problem?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use your animation as a .svg or .gif, then as cSharp mentioned in his comment, [background-clip: text](https://caniuse.com/?search=background-clip) will work on most browsers. Example below

```css
h1 {
  display: block;
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1002/4312/2868); //jpg/png/gif/svg work
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  font-size: 60px;
  line-height: 1;
}
```

```html
<h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</h1>
```